# How come Khalid has THAC0 of 21 (*bigger* than base) in BG:EE?

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced

Ok, so I installed Baldur's Gate Enhanced Edition from Steam today and I'm starting a nostalgia trip to the Sword Coast once again. I'm forming a party and considering my choices in Chapter 1. I noticed a rather peculiar THAC0 level for Khalid: it's actually *bigger* than the base THAC0. Is it correct? Or is it a bug in the game?

[image]

Or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4):

+2 from proficiencies means you are getting a penalty, not a bonus. A +2 penalty is normal when using a weapon you are not proficient with.

At level 1, Khalid's weapon proficiencies are Long Swords, Axes, and Longbows. For best effect, make sure he's using those weapons.